# How to use vice versa?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to write a sentence like if the condition is satisfied then then this will happen otherwise other way round.

I currently use below:

1. If He is positive about the situation then he will move left else he will move right.
2. If He is positive about the situation then he will move left, and vice versa.
3. If He is positive about the situation then he will move left else other way around.
4. If He is positive about the situation then he will move left, and other way around.

I just want to know which sentences is correct from the above. Also I would like know if there any alternatives apart from above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Merriam Webster *vice versa* can mean *with the order changed*, or *with the relations reversed* or *conversely*. There will always be two things exchanged, either relations or statements.

A typical use of *vice versa* would be

> If the North-South lights are green, the East-West lights are red, and vice versa.

In this sentence vice versa means exchanging red and green, ie exchanging the relations.

In your second example vice versa might be understood as exchanging statements, so the second part of your sentence

> If He is positive about the situation then he will move left, and vice versa.

would mean *if he moves left then he is positive about the situation*.

Your first statement is clear, but I would correct it to

> If He is positive about the situation then he will move left, **otherwise** he will move right.

Your third statement does not really make sense; what is "the other way around" if he is not positive about the situation?

Your fourth statement, corrected by adding  **the** before *other way around*, is hard to understand. It might mean the same as statement 1, or it might mean the same as statement 2.

Your second statement is logically equivalent to

> If He is positive about the situation then he will move left, otherwise he will not move left.

If this is what you want to say then I would suggest this is the best form to use.

Answer (score 2):

To use **vice versa**, you need two things that can be reversed. You only have one. You're saying:

- If he is positive about the situation, he will move left, **and the other way around**.

**There is no other way around** because you've only defined one way: moving left.

It can work if you add another player, for example:

> If Player A is positive about the situation, he will move left and Player B will move right. And vice versa. (meaning that if Player B is positive about the situation, he will move left and Player A will move right).

Comment: What if I have to write about only one player movement depending on the situation ?

Comment: If the North-South lights are green, the East-West lights are red, and vice versa. In this sentence vice versa means exchange red and green. In your example vice versa might be understood as exchanging statements, ie if he moves left he is positive.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the answer. What I have understood  that although the statement is grammatically incorrect, but somehow meaning is conveyed. What should I do for the correctness of the sentence for conveying both statement.